# How can I center the content of a col-xs-12 column in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a input box and a button. I want the button to sit on the right hand side of the input box on all `devices > 768 px`.

For `devices <=768 px` I want the button to sit underneath the input box aligned in the center of the col-xs-12.

This is my attempt so far:

```
<form id="signup-form" class="new_invitation" action="/invitations" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-3 input-position">
    <input class="form-control full-width" placeholder="enter email address" id="InputEmail" type="text" name="invitation[recipient_email]">
  </div>

  <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 input-position">
   <input type="submit" name="commit" value="JOIN IN" class="btn btn-cta" id="gabetabtn">
  </div></form>
```

This results in the following correct behaviour on `devices > 768` pixels:
[image]

However on devices <= 768 pixels the button is not centered but is correctly under the input box:

[image]

How can I center the contents of the `col-xs-12` div? I have tried `center-block` and `col-centered` bootstrap CSS classes neither of which seem to work?

**---EDIT---**
If i add text-center to the col-xs-12 div it correctly centers the button element but also centers the button in the col-sm-2 div as well as per this pic:

[image]

How can I make the button sit exactly to the right of the input text field, and also centered on the row underneath the input text field when on a device with <=768 pixels?

Answer (score 6):

Add Bootstrap's `text-center` to the class containing the `col-xs-12`

So change this line:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 input-position">
```

To this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 input-position text-center">
```

Comment: This works, except it then centers the button in the col-sm-2 div also. I ideally want the Join In button to sit right next to end of the input box, and centered when it is on devices <=768.

Comment: Hmm in that case you could use [@david-wilkinson 's example](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/34745193/revisions)

Answer (score 4):

please add 'text-center' class on your div=col-xs-12

it is default bootstrap class to align element center

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-2 input-position text-center">
```

Comment: Just define class with the properties

.classname{
  margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
   width:768px;
}

you can set this class in media query too
@media (max-width:767px)

Answer (score 3):

Try the following example:

https://jsfiddle.net/7frqL6rv/1/

CSS:

```
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .input-position input {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
  }
}
```

For viewports <= 767px, the `input` is set to display as block and auto margins on the left / right - meaning it centers to it's 100% width parent `<div>` of class `input-position` in this case.